# Defining an hybrid type with generics

Tags: typescript

In Typescript, it's possible to declare an interface like this:

```js
interface Foo {
    (x: number): boolean;
    bar: () => void;
}
```

meaning that something of type `Foo` is a function taking a number and returning a boolean and also has a method `bar`. I want to do the exact same thing but I want the function type to be generic, like this:

```js
interface Foo<T> {
    T;
    bar: () => void;
}
```

that would mean "a function of type T with a method `bar`" but it doesn't work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for intersection types:

```
type Foo<T> = T & { bar: () => void };
```